# Spring RestTemplate wont use timeout settings

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, hystrix

Having a problem with understanding how RestTemplate handles timeouts.

I configured `RestTemplate` as a `Bean` as shown:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate rest(final RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
    return restTemplate;
}

private ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    final int timeout = 50000;
    final RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(timeout).setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout).setSocketTimeout(timeout).build();
    final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
}
```

The value of 50000 is only a academic value.

I'm using my `RestTemplate` withhin a `Hystrix` wrapped Service Connector:

```
@HystrixCommand(commandProperties = { @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "SEMAPHORE") }, fallbackMethod = "fallbackActivityCall")
public Optional<ResponseActivityValue> callForActivity() {
    final StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(accessConfig.getTracking().getUrl());
    final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(buildAuthHeader());

    final ResponseEntity<ResponseActivityValue> re = restTemplate.exchange(urlBuilder.toString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, ResponseActivityValue.class);
    final HttpStatus code = re.getStatusCode();
    return Optional.ofNullable(re.getBody());
}
```

I tested it with the service to call stopped. Instead of the expected value of 50000, the method returns after 3 seconds. It doesn't matter which value i configure in te `RestTemplate`, it always returns after 3 seconds.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: whcih version of spring you're using

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use directly [RestTemplateBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html) builder to build you rest Template instance : as below

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate rest(final RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder
             .setConnectTimeout(50000)
             .setReadTimeout(50000)
             .build()
}
```

And try setting configuration for hysterix in `application.properties`

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=50000
```

or just in your the command directly (`@HystrixProperty`)

```
@HystrixCommand(
  commandProperties = { 
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "SEMAPHORE"), 
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "50000")  
}, fallbackMethod = "fallbackActivityCall")
public Optional<ResponseActivityValue> callForActivity() {
 ....
}
```

Comment: Using the Builder was my first attempt to use timeouts with the same effect.

Comment: Cannot detrmine result code, the fallback is tiggered. May be it is a hystrix cause.

Comment: could you post your Hystrix config

Comment: Is the one annotated above the method ´@HystrixCommand(commandProperties = { @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "SEMAPHORE") }, fallbackMethod = "fallbackActivityCall")´

Comment: I'm not trealy sur , try  setting in application.properties the line 
`hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=50000` , also , does this endpoint rreturn error or desired result ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186461/discussion-between-boo-berrita-and-piet).

Comment: So, i tried some things out. Hystrix is turned out to be the main candidate to play with those values. The timeout settings as you teached and i did before was right ok and correct. Thanks to @Boo Berr'ita to help me finding out the Hystrix issue.

Comment: You're welcome @piet , I'm glad that you fix your issue :)